# How to stop click inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I display some content inside iframe and this content is html. I want to block click on all hyperlinks. 
I tried the following and it works. But I do not want to use jQuery. How can I do so with vanilla JS?

```
jQuery('#htmlFrame').contents().find('body a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: You can use CSS `iframe { pointer-events: none; }`. Tested as working in latest Chrome, Firefox and Edge

Comment: The OP specifically asks for vanila JS

Comment: That's true, but if someone asked how to knock in a nail using a screwdriver wouldn't you tell them to use a hammer instead?

Comment: Agree with Rory. I din't know it could be done using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested but it should be equivalent to the below:

```
const htmlFrame = document.getElementById('htmlFrame');
const links = htmlFrame.querySelectorAll('a');

for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a parent div and apply something like

```
event.stopPropagation()
```